# Proper data access in Multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, list

I have Method which is used by multiple threads at the same time. each one of this thread Call another method to receive the data they need from a List (each one should get a different data not same).

I wrote this code to get Data from a list and use them in the Threads.

```
public static List<string> ownersID;
static int idIdx = 0;
public static string[] GetUserID()
{
   if (idIdx < ownersID.Count-1)
   {
      string[] ret = { ownersID[idIdx], idIdx.ToString() };
      idIdx++;
      return ret;
   }
   else if (idIdx >= ownersID.Count)
   {
      string[] ret = { "EndOfThat" };
      return ret;
   }
   
   return new string[0];
}
```

Then each thread use this code to receive the data and remove it from the list:

```
string[] arrOwner = GetUserID();
string id = arrOwner[0];
ownersID.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(arrOwner[1]));
```

But sometimes 2 or more threads can have the same data.
Is there has any better way to do this?

Comment: Can you post a [mre]? It's very hard to understand what's going on right now

Comment: if you just need to get unique Id by incrementing - use `Interlocked` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netframework-4.8  Or use `lock(..)`  Yes, your current code will be disaster in multi threaded scenario

Comment: @T.S. Ok but, Can you please give me an example I basically need to Get an item from the list and then remove that item safely(or not remove it if it's not necessary)

Comment: Looks like this might be job for `ConcurrentQueue` or possibly `ConcurrentBag`, but it's hard to tell what kind of abstraction your code is supposed to be implementing. Specifically, a hard-coded reference to the second element of an array (`arrOwner[1]`) is an unusual thing to see. You may be working on too low a level of abstraction and could benefit from more specific classes to capture what you're modeling.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Probably - `ConcurrentDictionary`. `bag` still doesn't guarantee uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with List just add little bit of locking

```cs
private object _lock = new object();
private List<string> _list = new List<string>();

public void Add(string someStr)
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
        if (_list.Any(s => s == someStr) // already added (inside lock)
            return;

        _list.Add(someStr);
    }

}

public void Remove(string someStr)
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
        if (!_list.Any(s => s == someStr) // already removed(inside lock)
            return;

        _list.Remove(someStr);
    }

}
```

With that, no thread will be adding/removing anything while another thread does the same. Your list will be protected from multi-thread access. And you make sure that you only have 1 of the kind. However, you can achieve this using `ConcurrentDictionary<T1, T2>`

**Update:** I removed pre-lock check due to this MSDN thread safety statement

> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List (read - multithreading), but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it's being read.

Comment: It's not safe to be querying a list while it's being mutated in another thread.

Comment: @Servy I updated answer and . Now, the list will be locked before accessing its functionality

Answer (score -1):

On a larger scale of application you can use .Net queue to communicate between two thread.
The benefit of using a queue is you don't need to lock the object which will be decrease the latency.From Main thread to Thread A , Thread B And Thread C the data will add and receive through queue.No Locking.